# How to run the Azure Cloud Service without using Sql Azure Database?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

My azure application successfully running with azure sql database,but now i want to run Cloud application with my own database servers because of their  data security. for this, we can establish the local database connection from our own systems with cloud application and connect to my database perfectly with following steps using below link,

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/261063/Azure-Virtual-Network-Connecting-Local-Database

```
              After this i deployed my application in to azure and it deployed without any error.but when i try to run  my cloud application using cloud url like xxx.cloudapp.net  getting an error like
```

"A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found.)".

Please give some suggestions why am getting this error.

Thanks,

PCSSCP.

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting using SQL Management from another machine outside of your network. I believe that there is no problem with publication in Azure Cloud Service, but a connectivity problem with your SQL server.

Arthur Oliveira

Answer (score 0):

You have to remote to VM and check SQL Server port is opened or not, the same with SQL Server machine. I used to connect local DB with cloud based application.

Answer (score 0):

This is an intermittent issue with the SQL Server.

Check this link if it helps,
[IntermittentSQLServerIssue](https://serverfault.com/questions/261369/intermittent-problem-connecting-to-sql-server)